# How to add class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I made a small function whose work to do add class in `<li>` when we clicks on <`li>`, but I want to remove that if it is already had with `<li>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="created" content="Tue, 22 May 2012 12:39:23 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
      color:#000000;
      background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    a  { color:#0000FF; }
    a:visited { color:#800080; }
    a:hover { color:#008000; }
    a:active { color:#FF0000; }
    -->
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

    $('.main').find('li').each(function(){

    $(this).live('click', function (){

    $(this).addClass('active')

    })

    })

    })

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <ul class="main">
  <li>first</li>

  <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
      <li>fourth</li>  

  </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just use `toggleClass` this will add or remove it as necessary

```
$('.main li').live('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

if you want to remove this class from elsewhere, you can add an extra line:

```
$('.main li').live('click',function(){
  $('.main li.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery function `.toggleClass`.

```
$('.main li').click( function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

That should do the trick ;)
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: when we click first li it is adding class active now i want if we click second li then first li class should be removed

Comment: As Jamiec suggested you can add 
`$('.main li.active').removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 2):

Better we can use .**on()** or **.delgate()** methods:

**Use of the** **.live()** **method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of** **.live()**:

https://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('#showDiv').on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work try...

```js
$("#button").click(function(){

 $(".addclass").addClass("add");



})

$("#button2").click(function(){

 $(".addclass").removeClass("add");

})
```

```css
.add{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="addclass">Sample text to add class on it</p>
<button id="button">Add Class</button>
<button id="button2">Remove Class</button>
```